# Microphone doesn't work after setSinkId React JS WebRTC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, media, mediastream

I'm implementing audio output device selection and faced the following problem:
Initially, I didn't hear myself because of the monitor selection as an audio output device. Then I changed the output device to my speakers and can hear myself. Then I mute and unmute my micro and can't hear myself for some reason.
Microphone mute/unmute code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!micState && mediaStreamRef.current) {
      turnMicrophoneOff(mediaStreamRef.current);
      setMedia(mediaStreamRef.current);
    } else if (micState) {
      turnMediaOn({
        audio: { deviceId: { exact: selectedAudioInputDevice } },
        video: false,
      }).then((stream) => {
        if (!mediaStreamRef.current) {
          mediaStreamRef.current = stream;
        } else {
          mediaStreamRef.current = replaceAudioTracks(
            mediaStreamRef.current,
            stream
          );
        }

        updateDeviceList();
        setMedia(mediaStreamRef.current);
      });
    }
  }, [micState]);

const turnMicrophoneOff = (stream: MediaStream) => {
    stream.getAudioTracks().forEach((t) => (t.enabled = false));
    stream.getAudioTracks().forEach((t) => t.stop());
  };

  const replaceAudioTracks = (
    oldStream: MediaStream,
    newStream: MediaStream
  ) => {
    oldStream.getAudioTracks()?.forEach((tr) => oldStream.removeTrack(tr));
    newStream.getAudioTracks()?.forEach((ntr) => oldStream.addTrack(ntr));
    return oldStream;
  };
```

When I'm changing the output device - I just change the state of sinkId I'm passing to my video component as a prop. Video component code:

```
 const ref = useRef<any>();
 useEffect(() => {
    sinkId && ref.current && ref.current.setSinkId(sinkId);
  }, [sinkId]);

return (
   <video
          autoPlay
          playsInline
          ref={ref}
        ></video>
)
```

Btw when I changed the output device again it started to work.

[image]